# C++: pointer to struct in struct definition questions

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

Considering that piece of code:

```
struct myStruct
{
    myStruct *next;
};
```

Next is a pointer of struct declared in the struct definition, right?

What's the utility of - next - ? How can I use it?

Comment: This looks like a singly linked list.

Comment: Since you tagged your question as C++ I'd like to point out that you most likely don't need to create a (singly-)linked list yourself, except maybe for educational purposes. You can use the `std::list` class template to perform the grunt work of juggling pointers for you - just pass a type suitable for modelling the payload to the template.

Comment: but he's probably a student and needs to learn data structures. You don't learn data structures by using the standard library, you write them for educational purposes.

In production code I would expect however to see people use the standard libraries unless they have a very good reason not to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like it's an implementation of a linked-list.

Comment: Not really an implementation, but the data structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use next if you want to chain such structures together to traverse them later. Of course, having other members in myStruct would make more sense.

example:

```
struct myStruct
{
    int       data;
    myStruct *next;
};

myStruct st_1;
myStruct st_2;

st_1.data = 1;
st_2.data = 2;

st_1.next = &st_2; //st_1.next->data is now 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The utility of this pointer is whatever you implement in `myStruct`. You can hold a direct relationship to other `myStruct` structs (through the pointer) using this pointer and directly manipulate them (i.e. like "knowing" about other objects).

For instance (note that for all intents and purposes, struct's in C++ are public classes),

```
class Test
{
public:
  doSomethingToTheOtherStruct() {
    if(t != NULL)
      t->touch();

  setTouched(bool touch) {
    touched = touch;
  }

  setT(Test* other) {
    t = other;
  }

  bool isTouched() const {
    return touched;
  }

private:
  Test* t;
  bool touched;
};
```

This class has some very simple methods which can demonstrate the power of using pointers. Now an example using it is below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  Test t1;
  Test t2;
  Test* t3 = new Test;

  // Notice that we set the pointers of each struct to point to a different one
  // This is not necessary, but is definitely more useful than setting it to itself
  // since you already have the "this" pointer in a class.
  t1->setT(&t2);
  t2->setT(t3);
  t3->setT(&t1);

  cout<< t1.isTouched() << t2.isTouched() << t3->isTouched() << endl;

  t1->doSomethingToTheOtherStruct();
  t2.doSomethingToTheOtherStruct();

  cout<< t1.isTouched() << t2.isTouched() << t3->isTouched() << endl;

  delete t3;

  return 0;
}
```

Take note in the results of this code. `t1` is never set to touched, but inadvertently (through the pointers), `t2` and `t3` become "touched."

Answer (score 1):

The fact it is a pointer to the same class and that the member variable is called "next" suggests it is a linked list, as others have pointed out.

If the variable was a pointer to the same class but called "parent" it would most likely be some kind of parent/child relationship. (For example GUI widgets that have a parent that is also a widget).

What you might question is why you are allowed to do this: the answer is that pointers to data -types are all the same size, so the compiler will already know how many bytes it needs for this pointer.

For the same reason, you can have in your class (or struct) a pointer to a type for which the data type has only been declared and not defined. (Quite common to do).

Answer (score 0):

That is correct.  This kind of nested structs are used in  [linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).